# Highlighting keywords

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to highlight keywords in a sentence by PHP.

This is my code:

```
preg_replace("/\p{L}*?".preg_quote($string)."\p{L}*/ui", "<b>$0</b>", $info->plaintext)
```

Now I'd like to know how to highlight next and previous words.

Example:

> The good guys don't always have to be warm and cuddly

If the keyword is **Cuddly**, it should result in **warm and cuddly** being highlighted. So the script should bypass ***and,or*** and highlight **warm** with it.

Another example and simple one (`good` is the keyword):

Sentence:

> This school is a very good one.

The result:

> This school is a **very good one**.

Comment: Please post some test data for us so we can see what the inputs look like, thanks.

Comment: Could you define a rule on how you are picking the phrases?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Right now this just sounds much like "Please give me the codez" to me.

Comment: @RayPaseur I mentioned the output in bold keywords

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im rule is to highlight the words before and after the $keyword and bypassing "and , or "

Comment: Right, What are the inputs?  I'm looking for a way to know that "very good one" matters in the second example.

Comment: @hakre I did tried my part by highlighting the $keyword and I want a tip on how to highlight words after and before that.

Comment: @RayPaseur yes , you are right , Good is the keyword. and one and very is the words next to GOOD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
preg_replace('/(\p{L}+\s+((and|or|a)\s+)*)?\p{L}*?' . preg_quote($string) . '\p{L}*/ui', '<b>$0</b>', $info->plaintext)
```

Just apply the same logic to the end, if you need "and *" after the word, too. [Here's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/57cQL2)

Comment: Thanks ,  that was it . The only problem is that this script is just searching for the keyword and the word before it . can we include the word after ?

Comment: can we add the word after $string to the highlight ?

Comment: @MacTaylor: Sure; like I said, just use the same logic. `preg_replace('/(\p{L}+\s+((and|or)\s+)*)?\p{L}*?' . preg_quote($string) . '\p{L}*((\s+(and|or))*\s+\p{L}+)?/ui', '<b>$0</b>', $info->plaintext)` [Demo of that](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jowLxN)

Comment: @hakre: What's unicode composition? It fails with apostrophes :D

Comment: @minitech: see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/pdtr15.html, also see http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: @hakre: Oh, I see. May as well use `\S` instead of `\p{L}`, then?

Comment: That would catch inter-punctuation as well. I would say more like `(\p{L}\p{M}*)+`.

Comment: @hakre: Aah, that's what I wanted to avoid. Okay, noted :)